# An edit that changed a question into an advertisement

Tags: discussion

[Solo Trekking to Annapurna Base Camp](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99938/solo-trekking-to-annapurna-base-camp)

OP's question was closed, and I agree with that.  But I don't understand why someone edited it to remove any hint of a question and make it look like an advertisement for what the OP was interested in doing.

I was about to flag it spam when I saw what had actually happened.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

The person who edited was a new user using a nick name that has a history of posting spam and being destroyed because of that.
They tried an edit this time and it was approved, by the question owner. Raises questions about them but not enough for action yet.

It is now gone, I rolled back the edit and handled the account as it deserved.